# Maven (surefire) test plugin excludes not working

Tags: java, maven, jboss-arquillian

I have following configuration in my pom.xml

```
<build>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.17</version>
          <configuration>
              <excludes>
                  <exclude>**/DocumentChangeSubscriberTest.java</exclude>
              </excludes>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      (...)
```

`DocumentChangeSubscriberTest` is an arquillian test that I want to run only in specified profile.
When I type `mvn install` all tests are run, even `DocumentChangeSubscriberTest` that I want to exclude.
How to exclude test from the default (anonymous) profile?

I tried `<includes><include>...` and it works fine - only included tests were run.

I saw [maven surefire test plugin runs tests even if they are excluded:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461519/maven-surefire-test-plugin-runs-tests-even-if-they-are-excluded) but this is not working for me. I also tried many versions of `maven-surefire-plugin` without result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, excluding tests works. It was as simple as mispelling my class name: `DocumentChangeSubsriberTest.java` instead of `DocumentChangeSubscriberTest.java`.

Comment: In my case, I had refactored a test class and forgotten a character... oops.  Thanks for reminding me to check this kind of thing.

Answer (score 17):

Although you already found an answer, there is a simpler solution.

There is no need to use `<excludes>` tag. Sticking to the **maven naming conventions** would be enough. Just name your integration tests with `*IT` suffix (for example: `MyClassIT.java`) and let `maven-failsafe-plugin` do its job.

Keep in mind that `maven-surefire-plugin` is designed to run your **unit tests**. That's mean all test classes that with the following wildcard patterns:

1. `Test*.java`
2. `*Test.java`
3. `*TestCase.java`

On the other hand, `maven-failsafe-plugin` is designed to run your **integration tests**, and will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:

1. `IT*.java`
2. `*IT.java`
3. `*ITCase.java`

Your arquillian test is surely an integration test, so renaming it to *DocumentChangeSubscriber**IT**.java* would solve all your problems ouf of the box.

btw. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25908693/1037316) may also be useful in terms of separation unit tests from the integration tests.

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: The downside with this (everything has a downside) is that it will be easier to forget that you excluded a test.

Comment: @BeritLarsen Not really ;) because I wasn't talking about any exclusion, but about separation of unit and integration tests. During packaging or  installation of the artifact, both kind of tests should be launched of course.

Answer (score 5):

Although the question has been resolved, in-case someone is having similar issues with excludes, I am posting this.
I had a similar issue where-in my excludes was not working for maven-failsafe-plugin. I was using excludes to exclude running some integration tests.

I was using `mvn verify` to run integration tests.

in my case,

```
 <excludes>
   <exclude>**/something/*Test.java</exclude>
</excludes>
```

DOES NOT work if I use the -Dit.test option

 i.e. `mvn verify -Dit.test="<some_package>"`

however DOES work correctly if I don't specify -Dit.test.

 i.e. `mvn verify`

Comment: As written in the plugin documentation (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#test), specifying it.test will override `excludes` and `includes`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, just to throw out another thing for people to look at: My maven-surefire-plugin, as person described above, was accidentally declared under `<reporting><plugins><plugin>....</plugin></plugins></reporting>` but of course needed to be under `<build><plugins><plugin>...</plugin></plugins></build>`. The top `<reporting>` and `<build>` specs were higher up and off the page so something to verify if anyone gets this same error.

Comment: This was also the issue for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answer in this thread (or at least a very similar one): [How can I skip tests in maven install goal, while running them in maven test goal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117589/how-can-i-skip-tests-in-maven-install-goal-while-running-them-in-maven-test-goa)

Take a look, it might be helpful! The simple answer is that what you are trying to do it's not an option without using a custom profile (but it's way better explained in that thread).

Comment: How to do it without that then? I need to tweak this rarely so dont remember how i actually fixed this.